# How to do variable as part of url?

Tags: python, url, flask

I want a structure my GET request URL where it follows:

```
/api/results?date={YYYY-MM-DD}   
(e.g. 2019-09-20)
```

I've tried

```
@app.route('/api/results?ddate=<string:game_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_game(game_id):
    print("game: ", game_id)
    return jsonify(game_id)
```

I've also tried:

```
@app.route('/api/results?ddate=game_id', methods=['GET'])
def get_game():
    game_id= request.args.get('ddate')
    print("game: ", game_id)
    return jsonify(game_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer already, if you insist on going about it as before here is how you can achieve it.

```
@app.route('/api/results/<string:game_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_game(game_id):
    print("game: ", game_id)
    return jsonify(game_id)
```

and it is even possible to extend your url then like this

```
@app.route('/api/results/<string:game_id>/games/../..', methods=['GET'])
```

depending on preference (note that .. can be a string eg results or variable eg game_id noting that for each variable in your url, there must be a corresponding parameter for it passed to the function). hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Considering your second code, according to the FLASK [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args), `request.args.get` is a `MultiDict` with the parsed contents of the query string. (The part in the URL after the question mark)... So you no longer have to put this part in your url. This is what your code should look like:

```
@app.route('/api/results', methods=['GET'])
def get_game():
    game_id= request.args.get('ddate')
    print("game: ", game_id)
    return jsonify(game_id)
```